# ReferenceTable overflow (jni android), array objects release

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm making game for android, in which i use some JNI. After a while i get this error:

> 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096): ReferenceTable overflow
>
> (max=1024) 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096): Last 10 entries in
>
> JNI pinned array reference table: 12-25 22:01:23.304:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096):  1014: 0x4052ffd8 cls=[I (28 bytes) 12-25
>
> 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1015: 0x4052fff8 cls=[I (28 bytes)
>
> 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1016: 0x40530018 cls=[I (28
>
> bytes) 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1017: 0x40530038 cls=[I
>
> (28 bytes) 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1018: 0x40530058
>   cls=[I (28 bytes) 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1019:
>
> 0x40530078 cls=[I (28 bytes) 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):
>
> 1020: 0x40530098 cls=[I (28 bytes) 12-25 22:01:23.304:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096):  1021: 0x405300b8 cls=[I (28 bytes) 12-25
>
> 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1022: 0x405300d8 cls=[I (28 bytes)
>
> 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096):  1023: 0x405300f8 cls=[I (28
>
> bytes) 12-25 22:01:23.304: W/dalvikvm(13096): JNI pinned array
>
> reference table summary (1024 entries): 12-25 22:01:23.314:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096):   539 of [I 28B (113 unique) 12-25 22:01:23.314:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096):   140 of [I 36B (28 unique) 12-25 22:01:23.314:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096):    20 of [I 44B (4 unique) 12-25 22:01:23.314:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096):   325 of [I 52B (65 unique) 12-25 22:01:23.314:
>
> W/dalvikvm(13096): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 7728 bytes

I read that i must release memory (i.e. ReleaseIntArrayElements), but i don't know how to do it in THIS case. I have 2d arrays in java, i pass them to native function and convert locally to vector>.

```
jstring convert(JNIEnv *env, string ruch) {
  jstring result;
  char *writable = new char[ruch.size()+1];
  copy(ruch.begin(), ruch.end(), writable);
  writable[ruch.size()] = '\0';
  result = env->NewStringUTF(writable);
  delete[] writable;
  return result;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_pl_game_yapapersoccer_Ndk_move
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint player, jint index, jint mode, jobjectArray matrix, jobjectArray matrixNeighbours, jobjectArray matrixWagi) {
    int matrix_size = env->GetArrayLength(matrix);
    vector<vector<int> > vMatrix(matrix_size);
    for (int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++) {
      vector<int> row(matrix_size);
      vMatrix[i] = row;

      jintArray oneDim= (jintArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(matrix, i);
      env->GetIntArrayRegion( oneDim, 0, matrix_size, &vMatrix[i][0] );
    }

    vector<vector<int> > vMatrixNeighbours(matrix_size);
    for (int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++) {
      jintArray oneDim= (jintArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(matrixNeighbours, i);
      jint *element=env->GetIntArrayElements(oneDim, 0);
      int rowSize = env->GetArrayLength(oneDim);
      vector<int> row(rowSize);
      vMatrixNeighbours[i] = row;
      env->GetIntArrayRegion( oneDim, 0, rowSize, &vMatrixNeighbours[i][0] );
    }

    vector<vector<int> > vMatrixWagi(matrix_size);
    for (int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++) {
      jintArray oneDim= (jintArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(matrixWagi, i);
      jint *element=env->GetIntArrayElements(oneDim, 0);
      vector<int> row(2);
      vMatrixWagi[i] = row;
      env->GetIntArrayRegion( oneDim, 0, 2, &vMatrixWagi[i][0] );
    }

    // something something, ruch is c++ string, all legit
    return convert(env,ruch);

  }
```

This works for first few calls. An example to release objects would be appreciated. Unless completelly necessary, I would like to keep 2d arrays in java and vectors of vectors in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know that if you call `GetIntArrayElements` method, you should invoke `ReleaseIntArrayElements` to release the reference. You could review the `jni.h` file to search the methods which named Release**. Hope this could help you.

Comment: I admit it, I failed. I previously iterated using *element, but when i changed to intarrayregion, i forgot to delete jint *element = ... line which was no longer needed.